# The allocation of variables in Swift

Tags: swift, string

Hi I have a question about the memory allocation for the String type. 
For example, in Java, when you create a String, which is not a primitive but an object, the program will create an address associating to it This can explain for many codes in Java, like when you make String1 = String2 that means you're putting the String2's address to the String1's case,... So how can we make an equivalence to this in Swift?

Comment: Swift's classes behave similar to Java's reference types. However `String` in swift is a struct.

Comment: You can use `NSString` instead, which a reference type rather than `String`, which is a value type. But if you forgive me for asking, but this begs the question of why you want to do this. Apple introduced value type semantics for a reason. See [Building Better Apps with Value Types](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/) or [Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/).